# vba loop till a specific value is found

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing code which writes the date of monday. For example for today's week i will write 3/3/14 and in the below cell the next monday date...

```
3/3/14
3/10/14
3/17/14
i will drag it till 12/29/2014.
```

I have just wrote some loop

```
sub loop ()
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "29-Dec-2014"
    Range("I1").Select
    Range("I1").End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = i + 1
```

Now my question is how will i write a code which takes the current Monday date and loop till 12/29/14. 
i am hoping i will get the solution here.

Comment: What do you want to do in the loop? Just write the date of each Monday until the 29th of December, 2014?

Comment: If you just want to get the values, you don't have to write VBA actually

Comment: Octavio : Yes...I want to write each monday date for every week till29th of December, 2014

Comment: Sam092.. I want to automate that process. that's why need help

Comment: like for this week the date should start from 3/3/14. Then Next week 3/10/14...then next to next 3/17/14..... and it should end on 12/29/14

Comment: Just enter the date for the first week, say in cell I1, then in I2 enter the formula `=I1+7`. Then you can drag that formula down and you will have the dates you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, as the comments suggest, it might be a slight overkill to use VBA for this, you can automate the process with VBA using a macro like the following:

```
Sub ListMondays()
    Dim PrintDate As Date, EndDate As Date
    Dim i As Integer

    PrintDate = Date - Weekday(Date, vbMonday) + 1

    EndDate = DateSerial(2014, 12, 29) '<~~ Define end date!
    i = 0

    Do
        ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = PrintDate
        PrintDate = PrintDate + 7
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until PrintDate > EndDate
End Sub
```

This will populate the cells from the active cell and downward with the date of every monday until it reaches the defined end date.